# Get server IP in expect script

Tags: linux, debian, expect, ufw

I'm trying to automate the process of adding ufw rules on multiple servers. I use an expect script to run commands on multiple remote servers and I would like to get the IP of the server that is in a specific range.

the servers are on the ovh public cloud and therefore they have a public IP and a private IP. I would like to allow access to some ports on the private IP. The expect script looks like this :

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

#grab the user
send_user "user: "
expect_user -re "(.*)\n"
set user $expect_out(1,string)

# grab the password
stty -echo
send_user -- "Password for $user: "
expect_user -re "(.*)\n"
send_user "\n"
stty echo
set pass $expect_out(1,string)

for {set i 1} {$i < 10} {incr i 1} {

        spawn ssh -t $user@192.168.1.$i "sudo ufw allow from X.X.X.X to $(ip a |grep '192.168.1' | grep -Po 'inet \K\[\d.\]+') port YYYY"

        set timeout 5
        expect {
            timeout {
                puts "Connection timed out"
                exit 1
            }

            "yes/no" {
                send "yes\r"
                exp_continue
            }

            "assword:" {
                send -- "$pass\r"
                exp_continue
            }

            " $user:" {
                send -- "$pass\r"
                exp_continue
            }

        }
}
```

I'm getting the following error when running the script :

```
can't read "(ip a |grep '192.168.1' | grep -Po 'inet K[d.]+')": no such variable
```

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to achieve ?

Comment: Expect uses the [tag:tcl] language which has its own syntax. if you are more familiar with shell syntax you can try my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect/).

Comment: I'll definitely look into it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expect uses the [tcl](/questions/tagged/tcl) language. In Tcl `$(ip a | grep ...)` is a valid expression though it's not defined in your code.

You can \-escape the `$` char or use `{ ... }`.

```
$ tclsh
% set "(ip a | grep ...)" "hello world"
hello world
% puts "$(ip a | grep ...)"
hello world
% puts "\$(ip a | grep ...)"
$(ip a | grep ...)
% puts {$(ip a | grep ...)}
$(a var)
%
```